# using the pattern: less (noun phrase) than (noun phrase)

Tags: adverbs, conjunctions

Would you please give me some examples with the pattern below, in such a way that I could understand what the bold part means?  I couldn't find such a pattern in dictionaries.

This is the pattern:

> Japan is **less** a country **than** a network of linked Mega-regions, anchored by Tokyo.

Comment: "patter" is how little children talk to each other. You mean to say "locution".

Comment: Or, much more likely, they meant to say "pattern" and made a typo.

Comment: See [sense 5 of *less* in Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/less), and also [sense 5 of *more*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/more), which is very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Less* can mean *to a smaller extent" or "not so much."

> Joe is not so much a man as (he is) a mouse.
>
> Joe is less a man than (he is) a mouse.

**Joe is a man, but he can be thought of as a mouse. That is, he is shy, timid, and quiet, like a mouse.**

> Japan is not so much a country as (it is) a network of linked Mega-regions.
>
> Japan is less a country than (it is) a network of linked Mega-regions.

Japan is a country, but it can be thought of as a network of linked Mega-regions.

To use the complete sentence:

**Japan is a country, but it can be thought of as a network of linked Mega-regions, anchored by Tokyo.**

Answer (score 1):

X is less a *this* than a *that*.

The idea is that X can be considered a *this*, and is usually regarded as a *this*, but when you think more deeply about X, you realize that it would be more accurate to say it is a *that*.

Comment: So, have I correctly got what you have just taught me? Japan is a network of linked Mega-regions, not a country

Comment: No, not quite.  The locution means that it is *more accurate* to call X *that*  than to call it  *this*.   *This* is not an inaccurate description; it's just not as good a description as *that*.